# How to deploy JSON codes in Email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json

I need a help for the project I am working on. I have task that we have to display ads from third party server in email; when email is being render on client machine.

Third party company who sources those ads; have given some instruction. I am copy pasting here; can anyone please help me how do i do this, in Exact Target HTML Email file?

I think it may can be done using AMP SCRIPT?

Here is what they wrote;

**HTML Feed Integration**

HTML feed integration is useful when it is not possible or desirable to run JavaScript on the client, for instance when the ad unit is inserted into the e-mail body.

Serialize the request as JSON and HTTP POST this object to the service endpoint. Make sure to pass 'Content-Type: application/json' header in your HTTP request.

**Testing endpoint**

https://insurance-test.mediaalpha.com/html.json

**Request**

{
    "api_token": "xxxxxxxx",
    "placement_id": "xxxxxx",
    "sub_1": "test sub id",
    "data": {
        "zip": "90210"
    }
}

**Response**

{
    "html": "html snippet",
    "time": 0.213
}

Comment: Anyone please?????

Comment: anyone interested in take this project as freelance ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a [SSJS Script Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/) to pull data with [httpget()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/http/HTTPGet.html) from the feed URL and store it in a Data Extension.  Script Activities have to be enabled in your account by SFMC Support.

Once the Script Activity is written, then you can add it to an Automation in [Automation Studio](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/) to refresh the Data Extension on some interval.

Then in the email you can simply retrieve the Data Extension row using one of the [AMPScript Lookup functions](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).

Comment: In this case, I will then Freelance this project :).